# Clip image to not extend past video background

Tags: html, css, video, background

I have a video background and an image on top of that video. The issue is that the bottom of the image extends past the video height and I want to be clipped so it stops at the bottom of the video. I know how to do this with a background image, but since an mp4 can't technically be a "background-image," I'm not sure how to begin.

HTML

```
<div class="ImageThatsTooBig">
<img src="image-thats-too-big.png" width="50%" />
</div>

<div class="videopad">
<video width="100%" height="auto" class="videov" autoplay="autoplay" muted="" loop="loop">
<source src="video-used-as-background.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.videov {
height: 700px;
object-fit: cover;
margin-bottom: -7px;
object-position: center;

.ImageThatsTooBig {
position: absolute;
top: 50px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
left: 0;
right: 0;
z-index: 9;
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div class="videopad">
  <video width="100%" height="auto" class="videov" autoplay="autoplay" muted="" loop="loop">
    <source src="video-used-as-background.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  </video>
  <div class="ImageThatsTooBig">
    <img src="image-thats-too-big.png" width="50%" />
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.videopad {
  position: relative;
  height: 700px;    /* change to what h you need*/
  overflow: hidden;   /* clip the overflow */
}

.videov {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.ImageThatsTooBig {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;        /* put image to the bottom of the parent container */
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);   /* horizontal center the image */
  z-index: 1;      /* image higher than the video */
}
```